# After Signing up to Sendgrid and filling in my company details I receive an email saying they cannot support my account

Tags: sendgrid

After creating a sendgrid account I receive this email.

We have reviewed your account and have determined that Twilio’s services cannot support your account at this time due to one or more of the following:

- Violations of Acceptable Use Policy
- Violations of Twilio SendGrid Email Policy
- Accounts with unresolved billing issues
- Inability to verify provided information

Comment: I’m sorry you’re having technical difficulties. I’d recommend reaching out to Twilio Support.

Comment: I'm getting the same error, did you manage to solve it?

Comment: I had the same with our company's details. Wrote back to that support email, no answer.

Comment: Happened to me too - this is just terrible, why is this happening?!

Comment: I have encoutered the same issue, twice

Comment: Terrible company. This is what happens when you put programmers in charge of sales. Got this when I tried to log back in: You are not authorized to access SendGrid, please contact Support.

Comment: Same problem here. Our old account was disabled because it was inactive for one year. Now we started developing our project again, and the support suggested us to delete our SendGrid SaaS from Azure, and create a new one. But, when we try to create a new account, we always receive the email that they "cannot supporting us". We contacted SendGrid again, and they just replied with a general email that said the problem is related to the: [Acceptable use policy](https://www.twilio.com/legal/aup) or [Email policy](https://www.twilio.com/legal/service-country-specific-terms/email). But is not true.

Comment: Stilling happening in early October. Annoying.

Comment: It keeps happening. After several attempts; changing emails, phone numbers, passwords, and even for different projects, I give up on Sendgrid. From now on, I won't use Sendgrid anymore, and I'll even offer migration to my clients to switch to other providers for free. Terrible customer service from Sendgrid.

Answer (score 0):

This won't help everyone, but I wasted a lot of time on this and thought I'd share what I learned.

If you're using the [sendgrid heroku addon](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sendgrid), the simple [answer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kQyfOLKPrOE&t=0m19s) is:

> there is a sendgrid addon for heroku, but it doesn't work

Yep. Crazy. The video is 2 years old at the time of this SO answer, but my experience is the same - it just doesn't work. The youtube engineer also mentions more at [3m 50s](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kQyfOLKPrOE&t=3m50s):

> Using the heroku addon for sendgrid does not work, it has not worked in my experience

So I guess if you used the heroku addon, try signing up at sendgrid directly, or using another provider.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I was using a Google gmail account. It can only be done with a private domain email. yourname@companyname.com